# Unique pairs of unequal arrays in J

Tags: j

Suppose two arrays of different sizes:

```
N0 =: i. 50
N1 =: i. 500
```

There should be a way to get the unique pairs, just combine the two. The "simplest" I found was:

```
]$R =: |:,"2 |: (,.N0) ,"1 0/ N1
25000 2
```

Which is frankly a butt ugly, baseball bat solution. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern of data you're reaching for is a variation on [Catalogue.](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d520.htm) It's the most famous variation, in fact: Cartesian product.

On the Vocabulary listing for Catalogue there's also code for Cartesian product. To get the list you want, just ravel and open the result.

```
pair=: >@ ,@ { @(,&<)

   $ N0 pair N1
25000 2
```

Comment: I wrote mine as `13 : '>,{x;y'`. I'm never sure of how to use `@`.

Comment: When there's a long series of simple composition, as in this case, Explicit form is nice. I strongly recommend using 4 rather than 13 as the left argument of Explicit, in part to emphasize that this verb is dyadic, but also because 13 is not entirely reliable. It is suitable for exploration, not for production.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in search of the same thing.

I've only came up with the following that are shorter but not prettier:

```
,/(N0 ,. ])"0 N1

;(N0 ,. ]) &.> N1
```

or in the form:

```
;N0&,.&.>N1
```

Comment: That's not bad. I spoke with kaleidic on Twitter (our 3rd J regular on SO) and we'll have an interesting answer later. I don't want to spoil it here :)

Comment: (Peeked at twitter) Duh! Catalogue! It's obvious when you know it... :)